# when creating a webservice with Spring Boot, how can I remove null elements when the response is marshalled?

Tags: spring, web-services, jaxb, spring-boot, spring-ws

I have a webservice that is returning null elements like `<ns6:LastPayment/>`.  I believe it's caused by adding objects that are empty, but I'd like them to be removed before sending to the client.  Would this be handled by the default marshaller?

My `@Endpoint`'s `@ResponsePayload` method is returning a `JAXBElement<ResponseObject>` - should I assume that Spring is using JAXB to perform the marshalling?

Edit: trying to add useful details

pom.xml

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!--allows configuration properties-->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have a wsdl file that I'm generating objects from.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wsdl2java</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</sourceRoot>
                <defaultOptions>
                    <extraargs>
                        <!--this allows "unwrapped" elements-->
                        <extraarg>-aer=true</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-xjc-XReplacePrimitives</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-xjc-XJsr303Annotations</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-xjc-XJsr303Annotations:generateNotNullAnnotations=true</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-xjc-XJsr303Annotations:JSR_349=true</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-xjc-XJsr303Annotations:verbose=false</extraarg>
                    </extraargs>
                </defaultOptions>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/CARetriever.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.krasa</groupId>
            <artifactId>krasa-jaxb-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

My `@ResponsePayload` calls a service which returns an object that the generated ObjectFactory uses as a constructor parameter.

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "RequestInfo")
@ResponsePayload
public JAXBElement<Response> getFnRetrieveInfo(@RequestPayload RequestInfo request)
        throws ResponseFault {
    return objectFactory.createResponse(myService.getReply(request));
}
```

My service fetches data and populates the generated objects for return

```
GeneratedObj generatedObj = objectFactory.createGeneratedObj();
// this *might* be an empty string
generatedObj.setSomeProperty = myserviceResult.getSomeProperty();
// one possible state is that generatedObj is null
generatedReplyObj.addChild(generatedObj);
```

Since the `Response` (which contains the `Reply`, etc) is returned to through the webservice, I'm assuming Spring's default marshaller is doing the handling.  In this example, I would expect a result like this:

```
<reply>
    <generatedobj>
        <someproperty>value</someproperty>
    </generatedobj>
</reply>
```

but, if the property is blank, it's still adding the object, which results in this:

```
<reply>
    <generatedobj />
</reply>
```

I'd like to avoid that (without lots of testing before inserting)

Additional edit: adding Reply definition

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "FNRetrieveInfoReply", propOrder = {
    "quickResponse",
    "fnInfo",
    "caseParticipantHeader"
})
public class FNRetrieveInfoReply {

    @XmlElement(name = "QuickResponse", namespace = "urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:qikrsp", required = true)
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    protected QuickResponse quickResponse;
    @XmlElement(name = "FNInfo", namespace = "urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:fn", required = true)
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    protected FNInfo fnInfo;
    @XmlElement(name = "CaseParticipantHeader", namespace = "urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:chdr", required = true)
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    protected CaseParticipantHeader caseParticipantHeader;
}
```

(each field has accessors, of course)

further edit:

Ok, perhaps another way to examine this might be related to [marshalling empty lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268598/marshal-empty-lists-as-absent-nodes-with-jaxb).  The difference here, though, is the depth and type of the objects.  How does JAXB marshal an object when it contains another object whose fields are null?  I guess I'm expecting the entire chain to get dropped, but I think it's only eliminating the outer-most.

Comment: Could you add some simple code to figure out how it looks like? Also give more details about configuration, which Spring Boot version? Which starter modules are you using?

Comment: Can you show your Relpy JAXB Bean definition ?